# Php fopen is not creating files in the desired directory

Tags: php, fopen

if my script successfully creates a directory using `mkdir($d, 0777, true`) but the same script fails to create a file in the new directory using `fopen($d.'/'.$f, 'w')`

Could the mode of the directory holding both the script and the new directory be a culprit?

all is well on my windows appserve environment but my webserver doesn't generate the required file only the directory.

Comment: It's probably a permissions issue. Echo/log the exact directory, then look at the permissions for that directory. You might be setting it 0777, but the server may be overriding you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @aynber, thanks for the response.. looking at the new directory using cpanel confirms its permissions is 777.

Comment: @fred-ii, I'm not sure how to make use of the info you've directed me to.

Comment: add the following at the top of your php file(s) --- `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and/or check your logs.

Comment: @fred-ii, will do and get back. I'm just not at my machine at the mo. thanks.

Comment: I've tried a few things now with no luck. Got nothing out of the logs folder. Tried putting the fopen line in a "while(!file_exists...)..." block with a counter to prevent infinite loops but the file is still not created.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, adding the line you gave me didn't produce any effect. (sigh)

Comment: Also perhaps informative is that I have no errors emerging on the script that's supposed to create the file.

Answer (score 1):

the trouble is my hosting plan not allowing something dompdf wants to do so I'm looking to update to a dedicated host, which will cost more.